# How do you build the Generic Math Template Library on Windows with Visual C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, build

Currently, I'm trying to implement a vector and matrix library for my project. After searching on the web, I found some suggestion and decided on Generic Math Template Library because it is more focused to graphics programming. After downloading the source, I found out that it can only be built (at least with less effort) on Linux / Unix using SCons. So, what I wanted to ask is, how do you build it for Windows using Visual C++? Thanks in advance.

PS: Also if you have any different opinion about my selection of library, please don't be shy to enlighten me. I am also thinking about switching over to Eigen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From where did you take gmtl?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ggt/files/Generic%20Math%20Template%20Library/0.6.1/

If you use that version it should be only an include of the header files, so that you don't really need any SCons or whatever.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the one. Anyway, it turns out I can't use any math library for this project. Thanks anyway. :)